# Android listview strange output

Tags: android, listview

I have an issue in a ListView. There are 19 items to be shown. Each row has a NumMesa value, from 1 to 19.
But in the list the rows 1 to 13 are shown correct but after row 13, the rows are repeated from 1 to 6.

Here is my code, may be you can find the reason:

```
  public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter         //has a class viewholder which holds
    {
        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView textName;
            TextView txtEstado;
            ImageView imageView;
            LinearLayout linear;
        }

        public List<ListaMesas> parkingList;

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<ListaMesas> arraylist;

        private MyAppAdapter(List<ListaMesas> apps, Context context) {
            this.parkingList = apps;
            this.context = context;
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ListaMesas>();
            arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return parkingList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
        {

            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content_mesas, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                viewHolder.txtEstado = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtEstado);
                viewHolder.linear = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linear);



                viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

                String numMesa = parkingList.get(position).nummesa;

                Log.d("mesa","mesa ="+parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

                Log.d("prueba","prueba numMesa todas las mesas "+parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

                if (numMesa != null && !numMesa .isEmpty() && !numMesa.equals("null")) { //aqui


                    viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

                    numMesa = parkingList.get(position).nummesa;


                    if (numMesa != null && !numMesa.isEmpty() && !numMesa.equals("null")) {

                        Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas " + parkingList.get(position).nummesa);
                        Log.d("mesa","mesa foos size"+foos.size());
                        for (int i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas " + parkingList.get(position).nummesa);






                            String orden = foos.get(i).nummesa;
                            String icono = foos.get(i).estado_mesa;
                            String id = foos.get(i).idTicket;
                            String numTicket = foos.get(i).numeroticket;
                            //String nuTicket = foos.get(i).numTicket;

                            Log.d("mesa","mesa orden mesa="+i);
                            Log.d("mesa","mesa numesa="+orden);
                            Log.d("mesa","mesa estadoMesa="+icono);
                            Log.d("mesa","mesa id ticket="+id);
                            Log.d("mesa","mesa numeroticket="+numTicket);


                            if (numMesa.equals(orden)){
                                if (icono.equals("100")){
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa);
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro MESA OCUPADA" );
                                    parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                                    parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                                    parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;

                                    viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);
                                    viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                                }
                                if (icono.equals("200")){
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa+" "+orden);
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro MESA EN LOS POSTRES" );
                                    viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                    viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                                    parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                                    parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                                    parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                                }
                                if (icono.equals("300")){
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa+" "+orden);
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro TICKET IMPRESO" );
                                    viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                                    viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                                    parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                                    parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                                    parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                                }
                                if (icono.equals("400")){
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa+" "+orden);
                                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro TICKET IMPRESO" );
                                    viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                    viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                                    parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                                    parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                                    parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                                }
                            }


                        }

                    }
                }


                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // here setting up names and images



            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is better way to use _RecyclerView_ instead of ListView

Comment: @Piyush, thank you for your comment, but I would like to know what am I doing wrong in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as Follows.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content_mesas, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        viewHolder.txtEstado = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtEstado);
        viewHolder.linear = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);
    String numMesa = parkingList.get(position).nummesa;
    if (numMesa != null && !numMesa.isEmpty() && !numMesa.equals("null")) { //aqui
        viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);
        numMesa = parkingList.get(position).nummesa;
        if (numMesa != null && !numMesa.isEmpty() && !numMesa.equals("null")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++) {
                String orden = foos.get(i).nummesa;
                String icono = foos.get(i).estado_mesa;
                String id = foos.get(i).idTicket;
                String numTicket = foos.get(i).numeroticket;
                if (numMesa.equals(orden)) {
                    if (icono.equals("100")) {
                        parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                        parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                        parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                        viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);
                        viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                    }
                    if (icono.equals("200")) {
                        viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                        parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                        parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                        parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                    }
                    if (icono.equals("300")) {
                        viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                        viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                        parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                        parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                        parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                    }
                    if (icono.equals("400")) {
                        viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                        parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                        parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                        parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

**Problem**- The problem with your code is `if(rowView==null)` will only get called if new view is required for this position. It will not get called when you will get covert view as an argument. This is how `ViewHolder` pattern works in adapter..
PS:- Move to `RecyclerView`. `ListView` is legacy now.

Answer (score 0):

you miss understand setTag pattern. will solve view only but you need to update it every time.
please update your code like

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
    {

        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content_mesas, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            viewHolder.txtEstado = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtEstado);
            viewHolder.linear = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linear);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

        String numMesa = parkingList.get(position).nummesa;

        Log.d("mesa","mesa ="+parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

        Log.d("prueba","prueba numMesa todas las mesas "+parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

        if (numMesa != null && !numMesa .isEmpty() && !numMesa.equals("null")) { //aqui


            viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);

            numMesa = parkingList.get(position).nummesa;


            if (numMesa != null && !numMesa.isEmpty() && !numMesa.equals("null")) {

                Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas " + parkingList.get(position).nummesa);
                Log.d("mesa","mesa foos size"+foos.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas " + parkingList.get(position).nummesa);






                    String orden = foos.get(i).nummesa;
                    String icono = foos.get(i).estado_mesa;
                    String id = foos.get(i).idTicket;
                    String numTicket = foos.get(i).numeroticket;
                    //String nuTicket = foos.get(i).numTicket;

                    Log.d("mesa","mesa orden mesa="+i);
                    Log.d("mesa","mesa numesa="+orden);
                    Log.d("mesa","mesa estadoMesa="+icono);
                    Log.d("mesa","mesa id ticket="+id);
                    Log.d("mesa","mesa numeroticket="+numTicket);


                    if (numMesa.equals(orden)){
                        if (icono.equals("100")){
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa);
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro MESA OCUPADA" );
                            parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                            parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                            parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;

                            viewHolder.textName.setText(parkingList.get(position).nummesa);
                            viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                        }
                        if (icono.equals("200")){
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa+" "+orden);
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro MESA EN LOS POSTRES" );
                            viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                            parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                            parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                            parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                        }
                        if (icono.equals("300")){
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa+" "+orden);
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro TICKET IMPRESO" );
                            viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                            viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                            parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                            parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                            parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                        }
                        if (icono.equals("400")){
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro " + numMesa+" "+orden);
                            Log.d("prueba", "prueba numMesa todas las mesas comparadas dentro TICKET IMPRESO" );
                            viewHolder.linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            viewHolder.textName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            viewHolder.txtEstado.setText(icono);
                            parkingList.get(position).estadomesa = icono;
                            parkingList.get(position).idTicket = id;
                            parkingList.get(position).numTicket = numTicket;
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
        }

        // here setting up names and images



        return rowView;
    }
}
```